# Company holding own shares in trust

Tags: australia, trusts-and-estates, limited-liability-company

If the assets of a trust includes shares in a company, can that company be appointed as trustee of that trust?

It's not clear to me how section 259A of the Corporations Law works in this situation.

Comment: [Insider trading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insider_trading)?

Comment: Insider trading rules would only apply if the company had issued marketable securities.  In this case, I am looking more at the situation of a Pty Ltd company.

Answer (score 1):

The trustee is the legal owner of all assets of the trust. Under 259A a company cannot own its own shares. Therefore, a company cannot be trustee of a trust that holds its shares. *Quod erat demonstrandum*

Comment: Except that's not exactly what 259A says.  In particular, does clause (b) of 259A mean that this situation is excepted?

Comment: Also what about clause (c)?  If a person held shares in company, and appointed that company as executor of his will, would the grant of probate be allowed under clause (c)?